# How to make an interface extends its own generic type

Tags: java, generics, interface, software-design, generic-programming

I would like to create a contract (an interface), with a generic parameter, which enforces that the implemented class must also be the type specified in the generic parameter.

```
public interface SelfDefaultAlternativeDetailSupport<T extends AlternativeDetail> extends T { // syntax error (extends T)

    default T resolveDetail() {
        if (someConditions()) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return getAlternativeDetails().stream()
                    .filter(somePredicate)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
        }
    }

    List<T> getAlternativeDetails();
}
```

## Example Usage

```
public interface CustomerDetail extends AlternativeDetail {
    String getName();
}

public class Customer implements SelfDefaultAlternativeDetailSupport<CustomerDetail>, CustomerDetail {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "default name";
    }

    @Override
    public List<AlternativeDetails> getAlternativeDetails() {
        ...
    }
}
```

In other words, I would like that when a class implements `SomeInterface<X>`, the class must also implement `X`, But the attempt above has syntax because I cannot make `SelfDefaultAlternativeDetailSupport` extends `T`. Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Really not clear what you're trying to do, and your example is incomplete. What design problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. From my example, I would like to create a `Customer` entity that has a **primary** detail along with zero or more alternative details. The class `Customer` itself **IS A** `CustomerDetail` that holds the primary detail. The default method `resolveDetail()` is simplified, only to show the idea that it will return the primary detail or one of the alternative detail depending on some business logic.

Comment: At the concrete class (`Customer`), I can make the class implement the detail (`CustomerDetail`) without any issue. The problem is, I want to generalize this structure into a contract to enfore that any classes of this kind in my system to have this structure

Comment: First of all, you cannot extend a generic type, type hierarchy needs to be known at compile time (or specified via reflection). Secondly, I still don't understand what design issue you're trying to solve. What are the base requirements of your application in regard to these classes? What functionality are you trying to implement and with what data?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a self-referential generic type:

```
public interface SelfDefaultAlternativeDetailSupport<T extends SelfDefaultAlternativeDetailSupport<T> & AlternativeDetail> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default T resolveDetail() {
        if (someConditions()) {
            return (T) this;
        } else {
            return getAlternativeDetails().stream()
                    .filter(somePredicate)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
        }
    }

    List<T> getAlternativeDetails();
}
```

Then you can have:

```
public class Customer implements SelfDefaultAlternativeDetailSupport<Customer>, CustomerDetail {
    @Override
    public List<Customer> getAlternativeDetails() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Just be careful to never use a different class as the parameter to `SelfDefaultAlternativeDetailSupport`. If you want to avoid the unchecked cast of `this`, you can [use `getThis` methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206), but I don't think it's really worth it.